# PayPal IPN and live accounts

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

A user clicks on a buy now button on my website which takes them to PayPal where they can purchase my item. I then receive the relevant information through my IPN listener. This all works fine with sandbox accounts.

To implement this with my live business account, am I right in thinking I don't need to worry about creating live API certificates etc? I understand this is needed when making API calls to live accounts but I'm assuming a simple buy now button doesn't need this stuff setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. You only need API credentials when you will make an API call. IPN is a push notice, so PayPal is sending the data to you instead. All you need to do is post the data back to PayPal to verify it and then process the POST data.